# Null Object Pattern in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, null-object-pattern

I'm trying to use the null object pattern in a doubly linked list in c++, but I can't seem to find a way to use it while keeping the code clean.

The problem lies in the following piece of code:

```
node->getNext()->setPrevious(node->getPrevious());
node->getPrevious()->setNext(node->getNext());
```

`getNext` and `getPrevious` will return a `NullNode` object if the next/previous node is a `nullptr`.

A use case where this fails - when node is the head node:

The following will set the 2nd node's previous pointer to a NullNode object causing a memory leak .

```
node->getNext()->setPrevious(node->getPrevious());
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to keep the NOP and keep the code clean from `nullptr` and class type comparison,

Any suggestions will be very appreciated!

Comment: A simple `if` check? E.g. `if (node != nullptr) { ... }`?

Comment: I did not understand the problem. If node->prev is NullObject wouldn't you want node->next->prev to be set to NullObject?

Comment: If I'm understanding you, this is a memory management problem more than a Null Object implementation problem. (e.g., If you use [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_smart_pointers "Wikipedia - Smart Pointers"), you'd see the expected behavior and without the memory leak.) In fact, you'd have the exact same memory leak if you weren't using the NOP at all.

Comment: @Lilshieste Smart pointers don't work for double linked lists, because of the cycles involved.

Comment: @JamesKanze Excellent point; completely overlooked that one.

Answer (score 0):

Things are simpler if you store the node previous and next, something like that :

```
Node* Detach( Node* node) {
  auto prev = node->getPrevious();
  auto next = node->getNext();
  prev->setNext( next );
  next->setPrevious( prev);

  node->setNext( nullNodeAddr);
  node->setPrevious( nullNodeAddr);

  return node;
}
```

The NOP or Sentinel pattern is a way to simplify operations to never care about null value at the head and tail of the list. If you need to test about it somewhere, then you fail.